# Center a div horizontally on a page when it is constrained to an off-center limited width div

Tags: css

I am working with a set HTML template that makes things a little tricky to customize exactly the way I want. So I am stuck with a structure that somewhat lacks flexibility.

I have a div that takes up 50% width of the page, but I want to center a containing div in the middle of the page. Due to other restrictions in other parts of the page, I really can't change the parent div being set to **position: relative**.

**This is the effect I am after:**
[image]

**This is the code I have so far (which is not working):**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div  class="centerpage"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Berlin_U-Bahn_Train_A3L71.jpg/220px-Berlin_U-Bahn_Train_A3L71.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    background-color: #85D782;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.centerpage {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `.centerpage { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; }`?

Comment: @JaceCotton that would center it in the parent, not the intended effect. I don't understand the intended effect either though - how is the size of the train image decided? What is it positioned on? Is it fixed size?

Comment: We need more context. Maybe a jsfiddle or a link to it live?

Comment: Please replicate issue in jsfiddle, so we know how to fix this. It's not enough context as stated before.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xM5u/ - you can see it there, the picture of the train is to the far left. I am trying to center it horizontally to the window size - *not* the 'parent' div that takes up 50% width of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the old method of absolute and negative margin :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Htpen

```
.parent {
  background-color: #85D782;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative;
}
.centerpage {
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:50%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin :-80px 0 0 -110px;/* negative margin is equal to half height/width of image */
}
```

or use a background-image or gradient http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GDbtg :

```
.centerpage {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,
    #85D782 0%,
    #85D782 50%,
    #ffffff 50%,
      #ffffff
  )
    ;
  height: 400px;
 text-align:center;
  line-height:400px;
}
img{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: i add to use codepen, unable to edit your fiddle, my screen being too small ... really not userfriendly to me this fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

```
put image into a div and apply class below 

{
width: 100px /* with your width whatever it is */;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;
height: 110px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

and add one more class
.centerpage img {
width:100%;
}
```